# I keep getting missing semicolon error in react

Tags: reactjs, syntax

I have this piece of code where all my parentheses are closed properly but I get this error all along my code 
[image]

and here is the syntax:(I kept checking and I found them all closed properly, can't find the reason behind all these missing parentheses and whenever I added semicolons as the error indicates it would end up with the same error at the next line

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Form extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    photoData:'',
    email: ''
    }
  }
  handle(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const{qrUrl}=this.props.qrUrl;
    axios.get(`${qrUrl}`)
  .then(
    (response) => response.json()
  ).then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      photoData:data
  }).then({
      method: "POST", 
      url:"http://localhost:3002/send", 
      data:  this.state.photoData
    }).then((response)=>{
      if (response.data.status === 'success'){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm()
      }else if(response.data.status === 'fail'){
        alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
  })




  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post({
      method: "POST", 
      url:"http://localhost:3000/send", 
      data:  this.state
    }).then((response)=>{
      if (response.data.status === 'success'){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm()
      }else if(response.data.status === 'fail'){
        alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
    });
  }





  render() {


     return(
    <div className="App">
    <form id="contact-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} onClick={this.handle.bind(this)} method="POST">


    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value={this.state.email}  />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"  >Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
   );

 }
}




export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the "handle" function is not closed properly, add two closing braces "}}" before "handleSubmit" function and your error might get fixed.

Comment: I did it and now I have only one error "missing , at line 34"

Comment: check my post again I will upload a photo of it

Comment: Add a semicolon on line number 33 and your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the braces in handle function -

```
  handle(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   const{qrUrl}=this.props.qrUrl;
   axios.get(`${qrUrl}`)
    .then(
     (response) => response.json()
        ).then((data) => {
           this.setState({
             photoData:data
           }).then({
       method: "POST", 
      url:"http://localhost:3002/send", 
     data:  this.state.photoData
     }).then((response)=>{
     if (response.data.status === 'success'){
        alert("Message Sent."); 
        this.resetForm()
     }else if(response.data.status === 'fail'){
       alert("Message failed to send.")
      }
   })
 }) // This one is missing
} // And This one is missing
```